# Where can I get the old, free version of Anjlab's SQL Profiler?

Tags: sql, sql-server, profiling, profiler

**Note: Although this question probably does not fit in with SO's usual programming questions, out of StackOverflow, ServerFault, SuperUser and Programmer's Exchange, only SO has any questions that make mention of this software, which is why I decided to post here.**

I used to use Anjlab's open source SQL Profiler tool, and found it to be invaluable. Unfortunately, it looks like the software has been converted to a paid version, with the all access to the open source version completely removed. Since this software is mentioned several times in questions here on SO, I was wondering if anyone still has a copy of the old, free, open source version and would be willing to share it?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I've managed to find the following:

<s>[SqlExpressProfiler-1.2.1812.13.zip](http://www.mdasoftware.com.br/arquivos/SqlExpressProfiler-1.2.1812.13.zip)</s> <-- You have to pay to use the performance dashboard.

<s>[SqlExpressProfiler-1.2.1708.7.zip](http://www.schoolpro.com.au/files/v2/Database/Tools/SqlExpressProfiler-1.2.1708.7.zip)</s>

[SqlExpressProfiler-1.2.1708.7.zip](http://helmpcb.com/misc/SqlExpressProfiler-1.2.1708.7.zip)

<s>[SqlExpressProfiler.1.2.1624.78.zip](http://content33.wuala.com/rawcontent/tP4DZc1rOtMK0_i6KexkyFdvGT2vfSYuuQXxqsQPJZufr7x5BD9pNMc2jMzRpVsWqjcz7reFbe9_vZu7o0qok13KW9c-Fe45y3CWJHXCcG9CT0-0BO4WaLrd_z5O8oOCfArQTHPFlPRV1JBMfOKZQwJDIDyvy2ZZTGCXbkNo618WffnBo8_mWH3tUkB9YCTbNObicvXUonKzhG_O2HRbT8Rud358ICq1x-B130erjv0/SqlExpressProfiler.1.2.1624.78.zip)</s>

[SqlExpressProfiler-1.1.1423.75.zip](http://data.itelix.pl/SqlExpressProfiler-1.1.1423.75.zip)

I'll be testing them out and eliminating the dud ones.

Comment: Thank you! The 1708 version is actually a "DataWizard" version though... and doesn't allow saving a trace.

Comment: no-installation binaries and source are [here](https://github.com/ren85/free-sql-server-profiler) for convenience

Comment: I bought the "not free" version recently and this is an executable of += 100k that each time you want to execute it, you must re download the program and authenticate your licence. WTF!!! Even if I bought this product, I will rollback to the free version which is an executable that you install and doesn't have to re download each $$%$/""? time. :)

Comment: @Samuel I did exactly the same. They're well within the rights to sell their product, but to take down the entire open source project and remove all traces is just.....

Answer (score 7):

Here is a simple alternative if you need just a monitoring tool for queries:

http://expressprofiler.codeplex.com/

I hope it won't disappear soon.

I'm currently using it with SQL Server Express 2012 to monitor queries form my NHibernate applications (didn't want to add log4net just for this purpose and show_sql outputs only to console window which I don't have in my WCF service).

Really nice and stable utility. I find it much easier to use than MS SQL Profiler which needs various settings, trace profiles for various server versions and what not. Express Profiler - just launch, hit Run, and all the T-SQL and sp_execute queries are displayed.

It's open source, you can add even more features if you wish. I guess, Clear button would be useful because now you have to Stop and Run again to clear the list.

Comment: The only thing I think this is lacking is the ability to filter things out of the results based on username, etc. Otherwise, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: A much better, easier-to-use alternative to the DataWizard product! Please, don't look back - go to http://expressprofiler.codeplex.com/ and check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [link](http://dea.vocord.com/pub/SQL/).  Use at your own risk.

You could also do a search for **SqlExpressProfiler-0.1.1094.67.zip**