# Profiler in SQL Server 2012 Express

Tags: sql, sql-server, profiling

I use SQL Server 2012 Express. This version doesn't have a profiler (preview query to db), it is accessible in version Standard which is not free.

Do you now any free tool, which has possibility similar to profiler?

Comment: Try old, free version of Anjlab's SQL Profiler
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11781910/where-can-i-get-the-old-free-version-of-anjlabs-sql-profiler

Comment: You can start a trace without the Profiler GUI, and you can trace to a table or a file and review it using T-SQL. Look up system procedures like sp_trace_create, sp_trace_setevent, etc.

Comment: Does anyone know if SQL Profiler is now included with SQL Server 2012 Express since SP1 now includes the full SSMS product?  Or are these still separate products? See SQL Server Express section on this page: [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200106(v=sql.15).aspx)

Comment: I'm not sure about 2012 SP1, but this feature is back in sql server 2014 express.

Comment: https://expressprofiler.codeplex.com/ - there is great, free tool to profile queries and commands to MSSQL

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's possible to run SQL Trace on SQL Server Express. See this link for more info: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/332293/How-to-trace-SQL-Server-Express-without-using-SQL

Profiler is in Standard Edition. It is also in Developer Edition, which is about £50 but of course you can't use it in production.

Comment: I'd be very cautious about this. Flags 4032 and 3605 combined will put a LOT of junk into the error log, does not provide all the information about who ran the query (just the spid#), and doesn't allow you to filter in any way.

Comment: I found this one: http://expressprofiler.codeplex.com/ Really nice and stable utility for basic SQL query monitoring needs. I find it much easier to use than MS SQL Profiler which needs various settings, trace profiles for various server versions and what not.